# Volume of a solid whose base is a circular disk

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a test in a couple of hours and i dont know how to do volume questions please help me out with thiss pleasee

The base of a particular solid S is a circular disk ( a "filled in circle") with radius 3. Cross sections perpendicular to the base and perpendicular to the x axis are squares. What is the volume of the solid?

Comment: Where is the $x$-axis relative to the base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can let our circle have centre the origin. So the circle has equation $x^2+y^2=9$.

We first want to find the area $A(x)$ of cross-section "at" $x$.

This cross-section is a square with sides $2\sqrt{36-x^2}$: big when $x=0$, and small when $x$ is close to $3$ or $-3$. It is $2\sqrt{36-x^2}$ because the cross section extends from the upper boundary of the circle at $x$ to the lower boundary of the circle at $x$. So the area of cross-section is $4(36-x^2)$. Thus our volume is
$$\int_{-3}^3 (36-4x^2)\,dx.$$
It is convenient to exploit the symmetry, and instead calculate
$$2\int_0^3 (36-4x^2)\,dx.$$
This makes the calculation a little simpler.

Comment: so if i do that integral i would get the answer i need? thats all :O

Comment: Either of the two calculations I suggested will get you the answer. As you can see, the integration is easy.

Comment: yes i thought it wouldve been harder than i expected

Comment: but i thought we were suppose to use some volume formula

Comment: and also does this have any units at the end i got 144. is it just 144 or 144  unit ^3?

Comment: A volume formula **was** used: volume is the integral from the beginning to the end of $A(x)$, the area of cross-section. The only problem was finding that area.

Comment: The $144$ is right. Whether one should mention units or not depends on what is expected in your course. But it is certainly correct to say unit$^3$.